# CakePHP: Updating multiple fields for one row (without messing the others)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to update only some information for a user. Specifically, I don't want to change the password. So I have my nice form with the data I want to change and my controller ready to receive that, even specifying the fields in the `$model->save($param)`.

I have the controller ready to validate all stuff including the **required password**. But I don't need to validate it, since I'm not changing it. Even so, I get a validation error telling me that the password is required.

I only want to change some specific fields, and I wish to do that in only one query (that leaves `$model->saveField()` out of the game).
Is this possible?

My controller:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->User->set($this->data);
    if ($this->User->save()) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The data array only contains the fields sent from the form, which don't include the password, and still, I get a validation error.

In the model I have the following validation rule:

```
'passwordConfirmacion' => array(
    'camposIdenticos' => array(
        'rule' => array('camposIdenticos', 'password'),
        'message' => 'La confirmacion no coincide',
        'required' => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
    ),

function camposIdenticos($data, $comparacion) {
    $temp = array_keys($data);
    $campo = $temp[0];
    return $data[$campo] === $this->data['User'][$comparacion];
}
```

Comment: Do you use Auth component ? Show User model.

Comment: No, I don't. I believe user authentication is not the problem in this case since I only restrict some pages via the app_controller and user is correctly logged in. I'll add more info in the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `'on' => 'create'` to the validation rule. That way the validation for the password is done only when creating the record.

If you want to keep the password validation for some cases later (e.g. when the user actually wants to change their password), add another similar rule but with `'on' => 'update'` and `'required' => false`.

Comment: If I do this, the password is not required, hence, it gets saved as an empty string '' and hashed, making the user's password useless.

Comment: Note that `required` is not the same as `allowEmpty` -- "not required" allows for saving the data without touching the password. If the system hashes and saves an empty string, you have a bug somewhere else.

Comment: I did have a bug elsewhere. I was not using ->create(), so the password was being loaded, hashed and saved again.

Answer (score 2):

set 'required' to false for the password field.
If you want to save certain fields, remember the Model->save() has the following signature:

```
save(array $data = null, boolean $validate = true, array $fieldList = array())
```

Comment: But the password is always required, meaning: it can't be saved or updated as "blank". But if I want to save other fields without messing the password field, I can't find how to do that. I would have thought this was trivial...

Comment: I didn't understand this at first. Now I see you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not do a manual save() there?
Instead of

```
$this->User->save()
```

try

```
    $this->User->id = $id;
    $this->User->save(array('User'=>array('field1'=>'value1','field2'=>'value2')));
```

**UPDATED**

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Cake still complained about an empty password, which was not being intended to be saved. I did that using the `$model->data` and checking that the array didn't have the password key set using print_r().

Comment: Have you set the the ID beforehand to specify which User you want to update? (I'll update my answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
//user.php
function beforeValidate() {
    if ( isset( $this->data['User']['custom_validation'] ) ) { // or another flag
        $validationSet = array();
        switch ($this->data['User']['custom_validation']) {
            case 'profile':
                if ( !empty($this->data['User']['passwd']) || !empty($this->data['User']['passwd_confirm']) ) {         
                    $validationSet['passwd'] = $this->validate['passwd'];
                    $validationSet['passwd_confirm'] = $this->validate['passwd_confirm'];                           
                }
            break;
        }
        $this->validate = $validationSet;       
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This might be interesting, but isn't there a common/normal/standard way to edit many but not all fields?? Do all people program these specific rules and complicated things in a framework that is meant to do this SIMPLE???

Comment: In the end, it was much more simple than this. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

i would use a behavior for this.
they can be attached on demand - in any of those register/change_pw actions you might have
http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/

this way you are not limited on "create" or other things. simply attach the behavior and add the pwd field in the form. thats all.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want the user to change his password on that form. I only want to save other data. I refuse to believe this can't be done...

Comment: of course this can be done. very easy - as a matter of fact. a) dont use required! b) dont provide the password on save. thats all there is to it

Comment: by the way: required=>true is never a good idea. see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/09/21/saving-model-data-and-security/ for details